# call python from nodejs on AWS lambda - permission denied

Tags: python, linux, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am able to call my python from nodejs on AWS Lambda using the below function. However, because I need specific python libraries, I created a virutalenv in the env directory. I zipped everything up and pushed to Lambda. But when I try and call python from the virtual directory I get a Permission Denied error.

I attempted to modify the chmod permissions on Lambda before calling python but got Operation Not Permitted. How can I get this to run?

```
console.log('Loading event');

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    exec('env/bin/python district.py \'' + JSON.stringify(event) +   '\'',  function(error, stdout) {
        var obj = stdout.toString();
        context.done(error, obj);
    });
};
```

Here's the error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Command failed: /bin/sh: env/bin/python:    Permission denied\n",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "",
    "ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:658:15)",
    "ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)",
    "maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)",
    "Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error most likely signals that `python.exe` does not have the executable bit set. Note, however, that even if you set the x bit, it won't work: `.exe` files are Windows executables, and they won't work.

> Note, this virtual env was created in windows. I also attempted from Linux in the i.e. `env/bin/python district.py` with no help.

`env/bin/python` is the correct command. If you still get the Permission Denied error, the it means that the file `python` is missing the executable bit.

In the AWS Lamba runtime environment, you are not allowed to change permissions of files, nor to change user, therefore **you must set the executable bit** (or any other permission bit you need) **when creating the .zip archive**.

To sum up:

1. On Linux machines, use Linux executables.
2. Set the executable bit of the executables before creating archive.

Comment: Thanks. point #1 should have been obvious to me. Point two I had attempted though perhaps I'm doing it incorrectly?  `chmod +x env/bin/python`  I get this error: `chmod: changing permissions of env/bin/python: Operation not permitted`

Comment: also if i attempt `sudo chmod +x env/bin/python` I get **sudo: command not found**

Comment: **Operation not permitted:** what filesystem are you using? Clearly not the default Linux filesystem (ext2, ext3 or ext4). **sudo: command not found:** what distribution are you using? Not all distributions come with sudo installed and configured. You may want to use `su` instead.

Comment: Correction: chmod may fail with "Operation not permitted" even if you don't have the permissions to edit the file. What does `ls -l env/bin/python` say then?

Comment: output : `-rw-rw-r-- 1 slicer 497 5120 Aug 13 15:30 env/bin/python\n`

Comment: filesystem `/dev/xvda1 ext4 /\n/dev/xvda1 ext4 /\n/dev/loop2 ext4 /tmp\n` . I'm using the AWS linux ami (whatever amazon uses for Lambda these days). I think it's similar to RHEL for the most part. Normally sudo will work if I were to boot up an EC2 instance using the same AMI

Comment: Ohh, I totally forgot this question was about Lambda, sorry! So, as you can see, on Lambda the files are owned by the user `slicer`, but your account runs as another user (`sbx_user1234`). Also, `sudo` is not available by design. Also, I was wrong about .zip files. Read the updated answer to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
exec('python district.py "'+ JSON.stringify(event) +'"', function(error, stdout) {
    console.log('Python returned: ' + stdout + '.');
    context.done(error, stdout);
});
```

Amazon has a tutorial on using Python in Lambda [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-python-in-an-aws-lambda-function/)

Comment: Trying to call a virtualenv python envrionment. This code does work to call python that's installed on the AWS linux instance, but trying to find a reasonable way to install python library dependecies